# exim redirect mail to a script

Tags: php, email, sendmail, exim

I am looking to set up a mail relay so that any mail sent to for example

@example.com

gets parsed be a PHP script.

I know to do this for indervidual address I could do some thing like

(from the following web site http://evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php)

Con figure an Aliases such as

script: |/our/script.php

then any emails sent to script@example.com will be passed to the script given..

but how can I make it that every email to @example.com is passed to the script? 
thank you

Comment: What is mail server? It should support some triggers

Comment: Exim, this is not a mail server just a relay. I don't want any mail boxes set up if I can help it. The idea is that you any email sent to the EXIM box will be passed to a script, which will then return a result to a user. For example they could send an email to pdf@example.com with a word doc attached and it will convert to PDF and send it back.

Comment: ahh I see now, I can use a wild card, so *: will catch every email and pipe it to the script.

Comment: Take a look at this [http://serverfault.com/questions/327598/pipe-all-incoming-mail-to-a-command-exim4][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/327598/pipe-all-incoming-mail-to-a-command-exim4

It might help.